# Postgres - Query for accounts with privileged access

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

Does anyone have a postgres query which shows all accounts with privileged permissions like admin/sa.

Basically trying to identify any accounts members of roles that have elevated access for audit purposes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define your exact requirements. "like", "admin" and "sa" are too vague.

Answer (score 1):

Run `psql` with the `-E` option: it will print out queries used for internal commands.

Then use `\du` to display all roles. There's the query you're after.